# How to get a ref of a component 3 levels lower?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I works with `<canvas>`, that's why i need it, i know that it usually smell, but not this case.

i have components tree:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
     <D/>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

only this is split into components.

How can i get ref of `<D>` component in `<A>` component ?

something like:

```js
// i use class components, it just for example
class A extends React.Component {
  refD = React.createRef<D>();

  componentDidMount() { 
    // do something with refD
  }

  render() { return <B innerRef={innerRef} />; }
}

const B = ({ innerRef }) => <C innerRef={innerRef} />;
const C = ({ innerRef }) => <D ref={innerRef} />;
const D = () => <div>yep, i'm just div</div>;
```

i've used `forwardRef`, but it works only one level

Comment: This is a code smell; maybe you should move whatever you're trying to do into global state

Comment: @DerekPollard, yes, but i works with canvas, and i need to get ref of <canvas /> and work with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the statements inside A's `componentDidMount` to a function and pass it as props to the D. After the DOM changes, you can call this function from D's `componentDidMount`

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    dMounted(ref) {
        // do something with D's ref
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <B  dMounted={this.dMounted}/>
        )
    }
}

const B = (props) => <C {...props}/>
const C = (props) => <D {...props}/>

class D extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.ref = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dMounted(this.ref)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div ref={this.ref}>yep, i'm just div</div>
        )
    }
}
```